# SSRS (SSDT 15.1.6, with Visual Studio 2017) no longer supports query building using query strings?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I haven't worked in SSRS for a few years. But I recently changed jobs and my new responsibilities include a heavy dose of report building. In my experience with SSRS I've always been able to build a dataset by including a query string. (See first image.) But I'm using SSRS via a Sql Server Data Tools install in Visual Studio 2017 for the first time, and I have been unsuccessful in sussing out how to include a query string when building a new report. This newer version seems to only offer a graphical, drag-n-drop solution. (See second image.)

How do I create a dataset that relies on a query string, or barring that, is there a way to build a dataset that relies on joined tables, with filters?

[Old query designer in SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I5Ip.jpg)

[New query dataset builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHzVQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can still write your own queries. Skip the wizard and start a blank report. Right click data sources and add your SQL server. Then right click Datasets and add a new one. Select "Use a dataset embedded in my report" and your SQL server as the data source.

Now you should see the query window and you can click Query Designer below it. In the top left of the query designer there is an "Edit as Text" button that will allow you to write it out.

Once you have your dataset made you can quickly get back to the query designer by right clicking the dataset and selecting "Query..."